Finding the upper bound for number of steps in Euclid's Division Algorithm
Context
I'm a student who has recently passed out of school and had started studying Ivan Niven's 'An Introduction to Number Theory', despite it being written for graduates, because the initial chapters like divisibility and congruences seemed simple enough for me. So I decided to test how far I could go. But I'm now stuck at Euclid's Division Algorithm itself.
The Problem
$(b,c)$ denotes the GCD of two integers b and c. $(c>b)$
Let j be the number of steps required to get the GCD by Euclid's Division Algorithm. $r_i$ is the remainder obtained by division algorithm at the i-th step.
It has been demonstrated in the book that
$$r_{i+1} < \frac{r_{i-1}}2$$
From this the author deduces that
$$j < 3 \ln{c} $$
How's that deduced? I tried to arrive at that result by myself but the result looks quite different:
$r_{i+1} < \frac{r_{i-1}}2$
By setting $r_0$ = c for the first step which is
$b = cq_1 + r_1$
and using $i = 1$ in the above inequality we get
$r_2 < \frac {r_0}2 = \frac c2$
Using the inequality recursively we get
$r_j < \frac c{2^j}$
${2^j}r_j < c$
Taking natural log
$j{\ln2}+\ln{r_j} < \ln{c}$
$ j{\ln2} < \ln{\frac{c}{r_j}}  $
$$j < \frac{\ln{\frac{c}{r_j}}}{\ln2}$$
How to get the GCD,
i.e, $r_j$ out of the inequality? Well I'm pretty sure that my approach is different/incorrect. Please guide me to the correct approach. How did the author get to his result of j being less than $ 3 \ln{c} $?
EDIT
Considering the inequality again:
$j < \frac{\ln{\frac{c}{r_j}}}{\ln2}$
For the upper bound to be valid for every $(c,b)$ where $c > b$, the bound should be as loose as possible so that it is greater than all possible values of j. For the RHS expression to be maximum, we have to choose the minimum possible value of $r_j$ (which apparently is the gcd of (c,b)) among all the possible pairs of $(c,b)$ ,($c > b$).
Clearly, the minimum possible value of $r_j$ is 1 (say for the pair (c,1)). Putting it into the earlier obtained inequality I get:
$j < \frac{\ln{c}}{\ln2}$
The approx value of $\frac{1}{\ln2}$ comes out to be 1.44 . So I have:
$j < 1.44 (\ln{c})$
which is a tighter bound than the author's $3\ln{c}$.
So I wanted to ask that is my reasoning and ultimately my result valid?
Also I would still like to know what was so obvious with that bound that the author has deduced it directly?

The natural log of $2^jr_j$ is $j\ln2+r_j$

The logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms, so that's $j\ln2+\ln r_j.$ Thanks for the correction.

@Lieven Well I want the number of steps, that is, 'j' on one side of the inequality, so splitting the log among the factors is not necessary ig since it has to be condensed back again after taking everything (except j) on the RHS of the inequality.

suggest you write a program   with these things:  steps(b,c)  goes through the Euclidean algorithm for those numbers and reports the number of steps (make sure that agrees with the  Niven). Then,  double loop, for ( b = 2 up to 1000,   for (c = 1 up to b-1)   report steps(b,c). Once it is debugged, run the double loop, but print out only when a new record number of steps happens, see if you can prove it.

@Kambin but the inequality $j\ln(2r_j)<\ln c$ is wrong. You cannot just put the $j$ in front of the logarithm and leave the $2$ and the $r_j$ sitting next to each other, that would be as if the $r_j$ had been raised to the $j$-th power in the original expression.

1 : gcd( 2 , 1 )  new  record  ////
2 : gcd( 3 , 2 )  new  record  ////
3 : gcd( 5 , 3 )  new  record  ////
4 : gcd( 8 , 5 )  new  record  ////
5 : gcd( 13 , 8 )  new  record  ////
6 : gcd( 21 , 13 )  new  record  ////
7 : gcd( 34 , 21 )  new  record  ////
8 : gcd( 55 , 34 )  new  record  ////
9 : gcd( 89 , 55 )  new  record  ////
10 : gcd( 144 , 89 )  new  record  ////
11 : gcd( 233 , 144 )  new  record  ////
12 : gcd( 377 , 233 )  new  record  ////
13 : gcd( 610 , 377 )  new  record  ////

@Lieven Oops, sorry for the mistake. And Thank you, I have made the correction.

@WillJagy Wonderful! Euclid's division algorithm leading to the fibonacci sequence. I ran the program and was awestruck! Thank you so much. Nevertheless, I could not progress much apart from proving that if gcd of $(c,b)$ is obtained in j steps, then the numbers b and c are greater than or equal to the jth and (j+1)th fibonacci numbers respectively.  Further I tried to prove that for the given number c, at the worst case scenario, the maximum number of steps will be 1 less than the index of the greatest fibonacci number less than c, but again did'nt have any formula for finding the index.

@Kambim The Fibonacci sequence is almost a geometric progression. You can get a Fibonacci number from its index via Binet's formula. For this exercise, you can simplify that formula.

From $F_n \approx \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt 5}$   with $\phi = \frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2},$  we get $n \approx \frac{\log F_n + \log \sqrt 5}{\log \phi}.$ With $ 5$  this gives $n \approx 5.0168.$   With $ 8$  this gives $n \approx 5.9935.$  With $ 13$  this gives $n \approx 7.0024.$   With $ 21$  this gives $n \approx 7.9991.$  With $ 34$  this gives $n \approx 9.0004. $ Alternates above and below the correct integer, and gets closer and closer
